# Dynamically create another row of images using Aurelia

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, aurelia

I am creating a mobile application using HTML, Cordova, Aurelia, and Bootstrap.  The application has the ability to upload images and create a row of thumbnails.  Being that this is a first time using Aurelia for me, the challenge is that I need a row to consist of only 4 images.  I need to have the application create a new row of images after the current row reaches it's fourth image.  I searched the web for solutions but didn't really find anything to suit my needs other than I might need to incorporate a value converter somehow.  Does anyone know how I would go about accomplishing this task?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I have included my original code below, which is pretty much the code I had before knowing that I would have to dynamically create additional rows.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" repeat.for="image of images">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src.bind="image | blobToUrl" />
            <div class="caption text-center">                                                             
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" click.trigger="setCoverPhoto($index)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Use as cover">Set Cover</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" click.trigger="removeAttachment($index)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove photo">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashley's answer is correct in this scenario.
Sometimes however it may be necessary to render a list with a wrapping element that contains x amount of items from this list.
You can solve this by grouping the list and iterating twice. Once on the grouped list and inside this loop another loop on the children lists.
You shouldn't pollute your VM with this grouped list if it's for UI purposes only, so it belongs in a converter. Example : https://gist.run/?id=9d624d96d86c7e0ad1c0919fd5fb8819

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'll look further into your suggestion because it just seems that relying on Bootstrap to do this is proving to be unpredictable as to how it wraps the images.  I need something a little more definite and consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code in a gist here: https://gist.run/?id=fb3631fe09d44395fd352c29e145c4a0

It looks fine to me as is.

Bootstrap is responsive, so you can't "lock" to 4 images per row, per se. It will go to one image per row below a certain screen width.

You can play with the dimensions in the images array in `app.js` to see how bootstrap will handle different things.

Comment: Thanks for your response.